# node.js process.env: assigning process.env property to undefined results in string type?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The node.js [`process.env`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) object seems to process property assignment differently than regular JavaScript objects. How can I get the `process.env` object to act like a regular object in this case?

Below is sample code illustrating the different assignment behavior. For some reason assigning `undefined` to a property results in a string type (only for `process.env`):

```
function demo(description, dict) {
    console.log(description);
    dict.A = undefined;
    console.log('typeof dict.A: ' + typeof dict.A + '\n');
}
demo('Passing empty object:', {});
demo('Passing process.env:',  process.env);
```

The resulting output is different depending on if an empty object `{}` or the `process.env` object was passed:

```
$ node test.js
Passing empty object:
typeof dict.A: undefined

Passing process.env:
typeof dict.A: string
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The `process.env` object forces all of its properties to be of type string, since environment variables must always be strings.  I'm not entirely sure on your purpose, but maybe you could try one of these as a workaround:

- Copy the `process.env` object into a new object, which will then behave normally:

  ```
  envCopy = {};
  for (e in process.env) envCopy[e] = process.env[e];
  ```
- Assign `''` to a property instead if you wish it to be 'blank'

  ```
  process.env.A = '';
  ```

  Which will then return false when you treat it as a boolean

  ```
  if (process.env.A) {
      ...
  }
  ```
- Or as *Jonathan Lonowski* points out, you can also `delete` the key from `process.env`

  ```
  delete process.env.A;
  ```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm emulating a bash script in JavaScript (in order to port todo.txt-cli). Both workarounds worked. Thanks!

Comment: You deserve more than 6 up votes for this. This is definitely unexpected if you are use to javascript (though maybe not if you really think about how bash works . . .).

Comment: That is absolutely retarded… Thanks for the clarification though—I thought I was loosing my mind.

Comment: This behavior is documented (and is deprecated). But, of course, I didn't mention that short notice about it, while reading the manual. I think, just like most people did :)

Answer (score 13):

This is occurring because `process.env` forces all of its values to `String`:

```
process.env.A = undefined;
console.log(process.env.A);        // 'undefined' (note the quotes)

process.env.A = true;
console.log(process.env.A);        // 'true'
console.log(typeof process.env.A); // 'string'
```

If you need to remove an environment variable, you'll have to [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) it:

```
function demo(description, dict) {
    console.log(description);
    delete dict.A;
    console.log('typeof dict.A: ' + typeof dict.A + '\n');
}
demo('Passing process.env:', process.env);

// Passing process.env:
// typeof dict.A: undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bypass `process.env`'s string coercion by using `Object.defineProperty` instead:

```js
Object.defineProperty(process.env, 'ENV_VAR_NAME', {
  configurable: true,
  value: nonStringValue
});
```

`configurable: true` is required if you want to do `delete process.env.ENV_VAR_NAME` later on.