# Trying to call enviromental variables with concatenating variable returning undefined

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, dotenv

Just encountered wierd issue, as far as I'm aware it's not a problem to access object names with concatenation, but it doesn't seem to work for `process.env` in `Nuxt.js`

Here's my enviromental variables:

```
    STATUS_AGREEMENT_NOT_SIGNED: 1,
    STATUS_BANK_AGGREGATION_PENDING: 2,
    STATUS_ID_UPLOAD_PENDING: 3,
    STATUS_BANK_ACCOUNT_NOT_SELECTED: 4,
    STATUS_DUPLICATE: 5,
    STATUS_FOR_MANUAL_REVIEW: 6,
    STATUS_DENIED: 7,
    STATUS_ACTIVE: 8,
    STATUS_FINISHED: 9,

    REDIRECT_1: '/profile/sms-verify',
    REDIRECT_2: '/profile/payment',
    REDIRECT_3: '/profile/documents',
    REDIRECT_4: '/profile/select-account',
    REDIRECT_8: '/profile',
```

When I try to call `REDIRECT_2` as process.env[`REDIRECT_${loan.status}`] where loan.status = 2 it returns undefined..

Here's how I try to call them and the output:

[image]

Anyone else encountered such an issue?

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10265271/2568469)

Comment: Thanks, I checked it out, but it's regarding the value always being saved in type String, I'm okay with that, but I should be able to access the value with concatenation right? Or with variable in general, because I just tried to use 2 as a key and acess it with loan.status only, but that doesn't work either..